# Error occurred while sending mail from web application after hosting on server in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am Sending mail with smtpclient Object. Mail sends locally, but mail sending fails when web application hosted on server(on BigRocks), I have following error occured.

> Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

```
        MailMessage mailmsg = new MailMessage();

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
        delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate,
           X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        };

        mailmsg.From = new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
        mailmsg.To.Add(xxx);

            mailmsg.Subject =....
           mailmsg.Body = .....


        }
        mailmsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com", "xxxx");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(mailmsg);
```

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to add trust level in web.config

```
<system.web>
 <trust level="Full" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response. But if i use this whole application not Displaying and This type of error occured             " An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
"